# Render markdown specified in Jekyll/liquid for loop

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to grab a file specified in the front matter of Jekyll page and and then render markdown in my template.

This just worked when there was only one key in the yaml, but I changed it to a loop and now I can't get it to render the markdown. It just spits out the values, and doesn't actually markdownify them.

My yaml looks like this:

```
additional_sidebar:
  - editorial-extra.md
  - editorial-extra-2.md
```

My Liquid looks like this:

```
{% for sidebar in page.additional_sidebar %}

  {% capture sidebar %}{% include {{ sidebar }} %}{% endcapture %}
  <section class="aside">
    {{ sidebar | markdownify }}
  </section>

{% endfor %}
```

The result is that it just spits out the values, instead of rending the markdown:

editorial-extra.md
editorial-extra-2.md

For reference, this was my original, working code:

yaml:

```
additional_sidebar: editorial-extra.md
```

Liquid:

```
{% if page.additional_sidebar %}

  {% capture additional_sidebar %}{% include {{ page.additional_sidebar }} %}{% endcapture %}
  <section class="aside aside-scroll fixedsticky">
    {{ additional_sidebar | markdownify }}
  </section>

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a race condition in your liquid code. You use the **sidebar** var in the loop and in the capture. Just change the **sidebar** for **sidebarmd** in the capture.

```
{% for sidebar in page.additional_sidebar %}

  {% capture sidebarmd %}{% include {{ sidebar }} %}{% endcapture %}
  <section class="aside">
    {{ sidebarmd | markdownify }}
  </section>

{% endfor %}
```